How do update props for a component/rerender said component to display mutated data
I have a test component, a test has 30 questions, I use the previous and next button to move in between different questions. Since having each page for a question seems like too much work, I want to rerender just the question component when the next button is clicked by changing the index of the current question. However, it seems to me when i update my current question index, the next question is not re-rendered. How can I solve this problem?
Here is my test component :
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import { Question as QInterface } from '@/interfaces/mongoose.gen'
import { Progress } from '@mantine/core';
import QuestionComponent from './question'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fetchTest from '@/actions/fetchTest';
import { Radio } from '@mui/material';




const Test  = () =>{

  
  const [currentQIndex, setCurrentQIndex] = useState(0);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QInterface[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuestions = async () => {
      const fetchedQuestions = await fetchTest();
      const parsedQuestions = JSON.parse(fetchedQuestions);
      setQuestions(parsedQuestions);
    };

    fetchQuestions();

  }, [setQuestions])

  const handlePreviousQ = () => {
    var qNumber = currentQIndex
    setCurrentQIndex(qNumber - 1)
  }

  const handleNextQ = () => {
    var qNumber = currentQIndex;
    setCurrentQIndex(qNumber + 1)
  }

  const handleChange = () => {

  }

  if(questions.length == 0){
    return (
      <div className='flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-center items-center'>
        <p>Loading Test</p>
        <div className='w-24 mt-4'>
          <div className='h-1.5 w-full bg-pink-100 overflow-hidden'>
            <div className='animate-progress w-full h-full bg-pink-500 origin-left-right'></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="my-12 mx-12 flex flex-col justify-between items-start">
      <div>
      <p className='p-0 m-0 text-3xl font-semibold'>Test #001</p>
      <div className='mt-4 mb-10'>
      <p className='p-0 m-0 text-xl font-normal'>Question 3 out of 30</p>
      <Progress className='mt-2' value={20}/>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-start'>
        <p>{ questions[currentQIndex].question }</p>
        {
            questions[currentQIndex].answers.map((key, index) => (
                <div className='flex flex-row items-center mt-4'>
                    <Radio
                    // checked={}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value="a"
                    name="radio-buttons"
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'A' }}
                    />
                    <p>{key.answer}</p>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </div>

      <div className='flex flex-row justify-start items-start'>
        {
          currentQIndex != 0 ?
          <button onClick={handlePreviousQ}>Previous Question</button>
          :<div> </div>
        }
        <button onClick={handleNextQ}>Next Question</button>
      </div>
      

    </div>
  )
}



export default Test

Here is my question component
import { Question as QInterface } from '@/interfaces/mongoose.gen'
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Radio } from '@mui/material';




const QuestionComponent = ({ currentQuestion }: { currentQuestion: QInterface }) => {



  const handleChange = () => {

  }
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-start'>
        <p>{ currentQuestion.question }</p>
        {
            currentQuestion.answers.map((key, index) => (
                <div className='flex flex-row items-center mt-4'>
                    <Radio
                    // checked={}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value="a"
                    name="radio-buttons"
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'A' }}
                    />
                    <p>{key.answer}</p>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default QuestionComponent



